# Choose columns being displayed in inbox (Outlook)?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

In Microsoft Outlook, the 'From' column in the list of emails in my Inbox is hidden, not sure how I managed to do it.

How can I get this column back?

Comment: what version of outlook?

Answer (score 2):

Should work in one version of Outlook or another.  Screenshot tour from Outlook 2007.

Right-click on one of the field columns at the top, such as `Subject`:

[image]

A menu appears.  Select `Customize Current View`.

[image]

A dialog box appears.  Select `Fields`.
[image]

Another dialog box appears.  As you can see below, you can configure what fields to show, and in what order.  Have fun!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Outlook 2010, the easiest way is to select the `From` view, in the `Arrangement` section of the `View` ribbon tab.